# How to get the amount onto my PDQ Terminal?

Tags: c#, .net, point-of-sale

I'll start by saying, I am *very* new to this.

I have a EPOS system that calculates the amount that is to be billed for an item/s. At checkout, a user has to enter the amount into the terminal, pass the device over and let the customer put in their card and pin.

I would like to be able to get the amount value from the EPOS system, onto the device, cutting out the part where the sale rep has to enter the amount, preferably using .NET

Is there a standard for doing this on terminal devices or is it device specific? The devices we are likely to use are Verifone, however by looking, it would appear that I would need to be a registered and certified verifone developer to see any of what I'm after, can I not achieve what I want without doing this?

How do I know which terminals will work with the .NET API?

Comment: Each brand of terminal has their own API for communication. There isnt any standard. You will need to get the API from whoever is supplying your terminals.

Comment: How is the card terminal connected to the EPOS system - and what manufacturers hardware are you using. Many manufacturers have .NET or C++ API. (In the instance of C++ you could write a wrapper)